# Convergence of an integral, without evaluating it

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove the convergence of this integral, but I can't figure out the solution.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin(e^x)}dx$

Comment: Please add to your post what you've tried, and point out where you get stuck.

Comment: Strictly speaking, $\sin(e^x)\not\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$, but
$$ \lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{M}\sin(e^x)\,dx = \lim_{M\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{e^M}\frac{\sin z}{z}\,dz = \frac{\pi}{2} $$ by Dirichlet's test and the Laplace transform, or the residue theorem, or other tricks.

Answer (score 1):

If we put $$e^x=t $$

it has the same nature than

$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac {\sin (t)}{t}dt $$
which converges by Dirichlet's criteria or by parts integration.